# SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "password/hr_main.log"

Tags: database, oracle, oracle18c

I trying to get the sample schemas HR set up for testing in Oracle DB 18c but I am getting error.

```
specify password for SYS as parameter 4: 
Enter value for 4: Pass1
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "Pass1/hr_main.log" 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

User created. 
User alerted. 
User alerted. 
Grand succededd.
Grand succededd. 
... 
Commennt created. 
Commit complete. 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
not spooling currently
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve it?
In third line:

> SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "Pass1/hr_main.log"

and in the last line:

> not spooling currently

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: In 4 line: SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "Pass1/hr_main.log" 
and in the last line: not spooling currently
How to solve it?

Comment: Well, it can't create that file... does the `Pass1` directory exist wherever you're sunning SQL\*Plus from? If so can you write files to it? Does the log file already exist and can't be overwritten?

Comment: Pass1 directory isn't exist. I can write file but I do not know what extension to give him. Log file too isn't exist. Can I change .txt to .log?

Comment: Hmm, if you're following [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-CB945E4C-D08A-4B26-A12D-3D6D688467EA) then you should have had a 5th prompt for the file path. Have you modified the demo scripts?

Comment: I following this and I hadn't 5th prompt for the file path. I did not modify the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this.
I had to add in tnsnames.ora:

```
ORCLPDB =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
)
)
```

Comment: How did a TNSNames entry enable spooling?